# Android in-app billing приложение вылетает при попытке купить товар

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Я решил сделать в своём Android приложении платное отключение рекламы. За основу взял [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/203368/). У меня получился такой **код**:

```
package ru.sccraft.scspeak;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DidableAdsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FileOutputStream fos;
    static final String SKU_ADS_DISABLE = "ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads"; // id покупки из Google Play
    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "***"; //ключ из Google Play
    private int rcReqest = 1;
    IabHelper mHelper;

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        private static final String TAG = "QueryInventoryFinishedListener";
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

            /*
             * Проверяются покупки.
             * Обратите внимание, что надо проintверить каждую покупку, чтобы убедиться, что всё норм!
             * см. verifyDeveloperPayload().
             */

            Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ADS_DISABLE);
            saveFile("ScSpeakAdData", "1");
        }
    };

    //Слушатель завершения покупок
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                return;
            }
            if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                return;
            }

            if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_ADS_DISABLE)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Purchase for disabling ads done.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                // сохраняем в настройках, что отключили рекламу
                saveFile("ScSpeakAdData", "1");
                // отключаем рекламу
                //ads.show(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled());
            }

        }
    };

    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
        /*
         * TODO: здесь необходимо свою верификацию реализовать
         * Хорошо бы ещё с использованием собственного стороннего сервера.
         */

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_didable_ads);
    }

    private void billingInit() {
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);

        // включаем дебагинг (в релизной версии ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО выставьте в false)
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

        // инициализируем; запрос асинхронен
        // будет вызван, когда инициализация завершится
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }

                // чекаем уже купленное
                mHelper. queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });
    }

    private void buy(){
            /* для безопасности сгенерьте payload для верификации. В данном примере просто пустая строка юзается.
             * Но в реальном приложение подходить к этому шагу с умом. */
        String payload = "";
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_ADS_DISABLE, rcReqest, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    }

    private void saveFile(String name, String s) {
        try {
            String text = s;
            fos = openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(text.getBytes());
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void buyDisableADs(View view) {
        buy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Ключ из Google Play я скрыл.

Покупка вызывается нажатием на кнопку. (onClick задан в XML.) Я скопировал в проект все классы из папки **/home/...../Android/Sdk/extras/google/play_billing/samples/TrivialDrive/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/**

**XML разметка**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_didable_ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ru.sccraft.scspeak.DidableAdsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/noads" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buyInfo" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/buy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buyDisableADs"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity вызывается при нажатии пункта в настройках (тоже задано в XML)

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/prefCategory_ads">
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/disableAds">
            <intent android:action="ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads"/>
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Конец лога приложения (краш) выгледит так:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ru.sccraft.scspeak, PID: 2344
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ru.sccraft.scspeak.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String, int, ru.sccraft.scspeak.IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at ru.sccraft.scspeak.DidableAdsActivity.buy(DidableAdsActivity.java:110)
                      at ru.sccraft.scspeak.DidableAdsActivity.buyDisableADs(DidableAdsActivity.java:134)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Лог взял с эмулятора. На телефоне тоже вылетает. На телефоне установлен APK из Google Play).
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас обработчик нажатий в разметке указан `android:onClick="buyDisableADs"` - это антипаттерн, не надо так. Вам надо или заставить этот способ работать (наверное надо метод переименовать, но кто-ж знает - никто так не делает) либо правильно повестить слушатель нажатий программно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Если это неправильно, то почему код стал выполнять метод `buy()`? В логе есть ссылка на строку 110. onClick на строках 133-135 (В логе ссылка на 134)

Comment: Неправильно не значит невыполняемо. Номера строк я не вижу. Может вы зря пользуете скопированные классы. Метод покупок вы используете устаревший. В доке другой предлагают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал. Теперь работает.

**JAVA код**

```
package ru.sccraft.scspeak;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ru.sccraft.scspeak.util.IabHelper;
import ru.sccraft.scspeak.util.IabResult;
import ru.sccraft.scspeak.util.Inventory;
import ru.sccraft.scspeak.util.Purchase;

public class DisableADsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DisableADsActivity";
    Fe fe;
    Button buyButton;
    IabHelper mHelper;
    boolean adsDisabled = false;
    private boolean показывать_сообщение;
    private String TAG = "DisableADsActivity";
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Ошибка покупки: " + result);

                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisableADsActivity.this);
                ad.setTitle("ERROR");  // заголовок
                ad.setMessage("" +result);
                ad.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.close), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                ad.setCancelable(true);
                ad.show();
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals("ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads")) {
                adsDisabled = true;
                // consume the gas and update the UI
                adsDisabled = true;
                fe.saveFile("scspeak-ads", "1");
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Реклама отключена!");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.adsDisabled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error here
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + result);
            } else {
                String цена = inventory.getSkuDetails("ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads").getPrice();
                if (!показывать_сообщение) buyButton.setText(buyButton.getText().toString() + " (" + цена + ")");
                // does the user have the premium upgrade?
                adsDisabled = inventory.hasPurchase("ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads");
                // update UI accordingly
                if (adsDisabled) {
                    fe.saveFile("scspeak-ads", "1");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.adsDisabled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    if (показывать_сообщение) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.notBuyed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    показывать_сообщение = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disable_ads);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.disableADs));
        setupActionBar();
        buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_buy);
        fe = new Fe(this);
        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "Ключ из Google Play Console";
        показывать_сообщение = false;

        // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true, "In-app-billing");
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh no, there was a problem.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);

                    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisableADsActivity.this);
                    ad.setTitle("ERROR");  // заголовок
                    ad.setMessage("" + result);
                    ad.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.close), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    ad.setCancelable(true);
                    ad.show();
                }
                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                restore();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) try {
            mHelper.dispose();
        } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mHelper = null;
    }

    private void buy() {
        try {
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads", 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "Язык: " + MainActivity.language);
        } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), R.string.unavableInThisMoment, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void restore() {
        ArrayList<String> товары = new ArrayList<>(1);
        товары.add("ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads");
        try {
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,товары, null, mGotInventoryListener);
        } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), R.string.unavableInThisMoment, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void buy(View view) {
        buy();
    }

    public void restore(View view) {
        restore();
    }
}
```

Классы пакета **ru.sccraft.scspeak.util** скачать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html)!

Товар (**ru.sccraft.scspeak.disableads**) изменить на свой!

**XML разметка**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.sccraft.scspeak.DisableADsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_buy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buy"
        android:text="@string/buy" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restorePurchases"
        android:onClick="restore"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

На кнопке "Купить" будет отображаться цена товара в местной валюте